# Dynamically create steps for jQuery Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated, jquery-steps

I am having some trouble dynamically creating some steps using the jQuery Step Wizard plugin.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>$.mobile || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="scripts/libs/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/libs/jquery.steps-1.0.4.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/libs/jquery.validate-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#wizard").steps();

                var wizard = $("#wizard").steps();
                wizard.steps("add", {
                    title: "HTML code", 
                    content: "This is a test"
                });
                wizard.steps("add", {
                    title: "HTML code2", 
                    content: "This is a test2"
                });                 
            });

        </script>
        <div id="wizard"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When this page is run, all that is shown on the web page is a "next" and a "previous", yet no steps at all.

The console error I am getting is this:

> SCRIPT5022: One or more corresponding step titles are missing. 
>   jquery.steps-1.0.4.js, line 1252 character 5

Can I have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you step through the code in the console?  It looks like the `$('#wizard').steps();` line is probably causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to include something in your call to `$('#wizard').steps();`

Look at the [basic example](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Step-Object).

```
$("#wizard").steps("add", {
  title: "Step Title",
  contentMode: "async",
  contentUrl: "data.xml"
});
```

Try changing yours to

```
$(function () {

  $('#wizard').steps("add", {
    title: "HTML code", 
    content: "This is a test"
  })

  .steps("add", {
    title: "HTML code2", 
    content: "This is a test2"
  });                 

});
```

Comment: I am getting this error from your $(function() { code: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'stepCount' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Try the updated version.  I'm shooting in the dark without an example.  Do you have a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        ***$("#wizard").steps();***    //remove this line from your code

        var wizard = $("#wizard").steps();
        wizard.steps("add", {
            title: "HTML code", 
            content: "This is a test"
        });
        wizard.steps("add", {
            title: "HTML code2", 
            content: "This is a test2"
        });                 
    });
```